# how can I call a query from a variable from an included file

Tags: php, mysql, variables, include

This is my code from my *query.php*

```
     $ubh = "SELECT
     ec_product.kode
     FROM
     ec_product
     WHERE
     ec_product.dtcode = '1' AND
     ec_product.kode_agencyplatform = '$kodeParnter' AND
     ec_product.kode = '$kode'";

     $qbaru = "SELECT
     GROUP_CONCAT(kode_category) 
     FROM 
     ec_product_category 
     WHERE 
     kode_product = '' 
     AND 
     dtcode ='1'";
```

This is from my another *ubah.php*

```
      include "query.php";
      $r = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "$ubh"));
```

How to call the `$qbaru` for *ubah.php* instead calling `$ubh`.

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Use the `$qbaru` variable? what's not working for you here? are  you not checking for errors?

Comment: Don't interpolate strings in SQL queries. Use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: your question is unclear, voting to close as such since you did not tell us what isn't working for you. Leaving the post also.

Answer (score 0):

Both variables are in the same file, so if you can call $ubh then calling $qbaru should not be a problem. If there is a error, then please provide the error.